# Three.js - how to implement occlusion culling?

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a game similar to Doom (https://github.com/maciejmiklas/ng-doom) - a large map with a user walking through it.

The `PerspectiveCamera` clipping is set to 0.1 - 2000. 3D Object is rendered when it's within the camera's plane, regardless of whether it is hidden behind another object (like a wall).

I hoped to create the whole world (Scene), add all 3D Objects right at the beginning, and that three.js would perform the rest, taking care of the performance. But apparently, I was wrong.

What is the right approach to efficiently render a large 3D world, without rendering unnecessary staff? Do I have to add and remove 3D Objects on the go to keep the Scene as small as possible? Are there any helpful design patterns?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as opinion-based, as there's no specific reproducible problem here. That said, for a DOOM-like game, make sure you NEED a depth of 2000. If your closest wall/object/target is never more than 500 away, you can use a depth of 501 and the render list generation will cull anything beyond that.